# How can I efficiently match what has already been matched in a Perl regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I wrote a regular expression to validate strings that must adhere to the following rules:

1. Must be at least one character
2. Must contain no blank characters
3. First character may not be punctuation
4. Last letter may not be punctuation
5. May not end in punctuation followed by digits
6. All other characters may be any UTF-8 character other than `/[:@#]`.

Here is the regex:

```
my $name_re = qr/
     [^[:punct:][:blank:]]      #  not punct or blank
     (?:                        #  followed by...
         [^[:blank:]:@#]*       #      any number non-blank, non-@, non-#, non-@
         [^[:punct:][:blank:]]  #      one not blank or punct
     )?                         #  ... optionally
/x;
```

See anything missing? Rule #5 is not enforced. I've been enforcing it by writing code such as this:

```
die "$proj is not a valid name" unless $proj =~ /\A$name_re\z/
    && $proj !~ /[[:punct:]][[:digit:]]+\z/;
```

There are a *bunch* of places I have to do this, so I would rather that it all be done in a single regular expression. The question is: how? What regular expression would reject a value such as "foo,23"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
my $name_re = qr/
    \A(?![[:punct:]])         # first character isn't punctuation
    (?:                       # start non-capturing group, repeated once or more
       (?![[:punct:]][[:digit:]]+\z)  # make sure 5th condition isn't violated
       [^[:blank:]:@#]                # match a valid character
    )+                        # end non-capturing group
    (?<![[:punct:]])\z        # last character isn't punctuation
/x;
```

Note that I moved the anchors inside of the regex, this may not be completely necessary with your current method but I think it makes it more clear to have it all in one place.

`(?!...)` and `(?<!...)` are negative lookaheads and lookbehinds, respectively.  They make it pretty simple to verify things like this, essentially the middle section can be "match these valid characters", with the lookahead/lookbehind at beginning and end to check those conditions.

The negative lookahead in the middle verifies that at the given position, we cannot match to the end of the string with only punctuation or digits, or in other words it checks to make sure that condition 5 isn't violated.  Because this lookahead is within the repeated group, it is checked at every position.

This would be simpler if you could use a variable length lookbehind, but I don't think Perl supports them.

Comment: That does not prohibit strings that end in a punctuation plus any digits, which is `/[[:punct:]][[:digit:]]*/`. And look behinds must be fixed-width, so the `*` cannot be used. :-(

Comment: This emits "valid", but should emit "invalid": `perl -E 'say "foo,23" =~ /\A(?![:punct:])(?:(?![:punct:]\d+$)[^[:blank:]:@#])+(?<![:punct:])\z/ ? "valid" : "invalid"'`.

Comment: @theory - There is no repetition in my lookbehind, and I made some minor edits but it has always checked for the punctuation and digits at end (I only switched `\d` to `[:digit:]` and changed the `$` in the lookahead to `\z`).

Comment: @theory - Sorry, I am a bit unfamiliar with how the POSIX character classes work, I think it should be working properly now after switching from `[:punct:]` to `[[:punct:]]` and other similar changes.

Comment: Yes, this emits "invalid": `perl -E 'say "foo,23" =~ /\A(?![[:punct:]])(?:(?![[:punct:]][[:digit:]]+\z)[^[:blank:]:@#])+(?<![[:punct:]])\z/ ? "valid" : "invalid"'`. Very interesting, need to study it…

Comment: @theory - To help understand how this works, consider the regex `\A((?!bar\z).)+\z` trying to match `foobar`.  The match will fail, because even though it basically boils down to `\A.+\z`, before each character is matched by the `.` we assert that we cannot match `bar\z` at the current location.

Comment: Yeah, I got it figured out, and have just tested it in my code and [committed it](https://github.com/theory/sqitch/commit/622c9a1b8df59f24d7cd013113a00382e98a2761). Works great, thank you! The key was to use multiple look arounds, which never occurred to me. Will mentally file this away for future use.

Comment: So rather than matching "stuff not followed by :punct:" your matching "end of string not preceded by :punct:"   That's quite nice.

Comment: Bah! Found a string that should match, but does not! `v1.0-1b`. It will match if the `.` is removed. But it should match with it there!

Comment: Fixed; will add separate answer with the refinement.

Answer (score 0):

@f-j's answer is correct for matching a complete string, but also need a variant that can match as part of a larger string with other stuff in it. Here's that version:

```
my $name_re = qr/
    (?![[:punct:]])                # first character isn't punctuation
    (?:                            # start non-capturing group, repeated once or more ...
       (?!                         #    negative look ahead for...
           [[:punct:]]             #       punctuation
           [[:digit:]]+            #       digits
           (?:$|[[:blank:]])       #       eol or blank
       )                           #    ...
       [^[:blank:]:@#]             #     match a valid character
    )+                             # ... end non-capturing group
    (?<![[:punct:]])\b             # last character isn't punctuation
/x;
```